# Change names of attachments : wp_mail PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, email, attachment, names

I'm using wp_mail to send mails with a form which is on my website. But when i attach some files, names are like "phpr0vAqT" or "phpFO0ZoT".

```
$files = array(); //Array pour les fichiers
$count = count(array_filter($_FILES['fichier']['name'])); //Compte le nombre de fichiers

        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){ //boucle sur chaque fichier

            array_push($files, $_FILES['fichier']['tmp_name'][$i]); //insere le fichier dans l'array $files

         }
```

I think the issue is coming from the : ['tmp_name'] , but i don't know what can i change because wp_mail need a path.

Then, i'm doing this :

```
wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $files);
```

to send the mail.

Thanks.

Comment: Since WP 6.2 you can set the filenames as keys of the array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77153782/1152843

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change attachment names with wp_mail.

A possible solution is:

1. save the files with the correct name.
2. send the new files with wp_mail.
3. remove the files.

Comment: I will do that, some guys change the core of wordpress but there isn't good for future updates. Thanks Bjorn for your answer.

Comment: Yeah seems like the only solution for that problem … pretty poor what wordpress doing here … at least they could give us all the options that the phpmailer class theyre using have.

Answer (score 6):

To change attachment names you should use `phpmailer_init` action for direct access to `PHPMailer` instance used in `wp_mail()` instead of passing `$files` as function parameter:

```
function prefix_phpmailer_init(PHPMailer $phpmailer) {
    $count = count($_FILES['fichier']['tmp_name']); //Count the number of files
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { //loop on each file
        if (empty($_FILES['fichier']['error'][$i]))
            $phpmailer->addAttachment($_FILES['fichier']['tmp_name'][$i], $_FILES['fichier']['name'][$i]); //Pass both path and name
    }
}

add_action('phpmailer_init', 'prefix_phpmailer_init');
wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
remove_action('phpmailer_init', 'prefix_phpmailer_init');
```

Comment: Nice unobtrusive solution until this is supported natively in wp_mail(). Trac ticket for that: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28407

Answer (score 5):

The above approach is correct, here is an example of how you can do that in php / wp. Hope this helps!

```
if(!empty($_FILES['upload-attachment']['tmp_name'])){
            //rename the uploaded file
            $file_path = dirname($_FILES['upload-attachment']['tmp_name']);
            $new_file_uri = $file_path.'/'.$_FILES['upload-attachment']['name'];
            $moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload-attachment']['tmp_name'], $new_file_uri);
            $attachment_file = $moved ? $new_file_uri : $_FILES['upload-attachment']['tmp_name'];
            $attachments[] = $attachment_file;
 }
```

And after finish with the attachment, you should clean up

```
unlink($attachment_file);
```

Comment: $_FILES['upload-attachment']['name'] can be changed by client to '../etc/hosts'...

Answer (score 2):

Since WP 6.2 you can set the filenames as keys of the array:

```
$attachments = [
    'filename1.txt'  => '/path/to/the/file1',
    'file_name2.pdf' => '/path/to/file2',
];

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
```